# "Go places on foot" or "go to places on foot"?

Tags: prepositions

Could you tell me if I need to add to in the following sentence?

> I prefer to go (**to**) places on foot.

What I am trying to say is that I am gettig around my city on foot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"*I prefer to go places on foot*" is natural and correct for North America, and means, "My preferred form of transportation is walking."

The following sentence, though less common, has the same meaning:

> "I prefer to go on foot."

So, "*I prefer to go [to places] on foot*" is redundant, because it only adds "to places" to the sentence above. If you're going somewhere, then obviously it's a place --everywhere is a place-- so no need to add "to places".

Answer (score -1):

It's always "go to" when you refer to a place

### go + to + location

> I prefer going **to** places on foot.

The only exemption that comes to mind is *home*, which does not require the preposion "to", for example

1. She goes home at 7pm
2. When the movie ended, they went home on foot.

Comment: It's always go **to** a _specific_ place, but in US English "go places" for travel is common. In particular, "going places" is a common idiomatic expression, often used metaphorically as in "His career is really going places".

Comment: @MikeScott Interesting, would an American ever say "I go places on foot"? Like you said, someone who's "going places" can describe a successful career.

Comment: When I hear _go places_ for motion I assume the speaker is from the US as @MikeScott suggests. I would not expect to hear it in the UK though.

Comment: @mdewey I'm going to disagree slightly: just 5 results for ["prefer go places"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22prefer+go+places%22&oq=%22prefer+go+places%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.6885j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and only  22 hits for ["prefer to go places“](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk01CTZ8_PaLmoBTAfh0p9McdOVLsmw%3A1601643311089&ei=LyN3X8j5BJGChbIPj5-nsA4&q=%22prefer+to+go+places%22&oq=%22prefer+to+go+places%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQA1CD4wJYs-cCYJTuAmgAcAB4AYABwQOIAdMGkgEHMS4yLjQtMZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrAAQE&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiIzfSk-pXsAhURQUEAHY_PCeYQ4dUDCA0&uact=5)

Comment: But those are both about _go places_ not _got to places_ unless I have mis-understood you.

Comment: It seemed that you were endorsing [prefer] go places i.e. "location" from an American dialect point of view. I haven't found any supporting references that suggest it is commonly said in the US. However, the informal phrase "go places" referring to someone with promising talent is said on both sides of the Atlantic :)